MEMORYCLERK_XE SQL server Memory will not clear on 2016
I came across this article regarding the 2012 CU update:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2965758-fix-memory-leak-occurs-when-you-start-and-stop-an-xevent-session-repeatedly-in-sql-server-2012-f8fe67e2-c5fc-a279-7296-da8349b0c6ea.
I am observing similar behavior in SQL Server 2016. Is anyone else experiencing this issue on 2016? If so, have you found a workaround other than performing a parallel migration?
Reboot will fix it temporarily, I have checked for known bugs in all the CU and I was not able to see any mention of it.

Not much to go on as there's no data. Are you able to show memory over time, your current XE sessions and their event list, etc.?
